# cv::imwrite causes access violation... sometimes

Tags: c++, opencv

I was trying out the example on [OpenCV Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) on imwrite, and I seem to have sporadic problems with it. The code below runs most of the time, but every now and then it fails with the exception message:

> Access violation reading location 0x010B3000.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
void createAlphaMat(Mat &mat)
{
    CV_Assert(mat.channels() == 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.cols; ++j) {
            Vec4b& bgra = mat.at<Vec4b>(i, j);
            bgra[0] = UCHAR_MAX; // Blue
            bgra[1] = saturate_cast<uchar>((float (mat.cols - j)) / ((float)mat.cols) * UCHAR_MAX); // Green
            bgra[2] = saturate_cast<uchar>((float (mat.rows - i)) / ((float)mat.rows) * UCHAR_MAX); // Red
            bgra[3] = saturate_cast<uchar>(0.5 * (bgra[1] + bgra[2])); // Alpha
        }
    }
}
int main(int argv, char **argc)
{
    std::cout << cv::getBuildInformation().c_str() << std::endl; 
    // Create mat with alpha channel
    Mat mat(480, 640, CV_8UC4);
    createAlphaMat(mat);
    vector<int> compression_params;
    compression_params.push_back(IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
    compression_params.push_back(9);
    try {
        imwrite("alpha.png", mat, compression_params);
    }
    catch (cv::Exception& ex) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Exception converting image to PNG format: %s\n", ex.what());
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Saved PNG file with alpha data.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I look into the call stack of imwrite, it seems that the params variable passed from my main function is corrupted (params.size() becomes 1073741810)

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Here is my build information:

```
General configuration for OpenCV 3.1.0 
=====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Platform:
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.10586 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.5.0-rc3
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 14 2015
    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1900

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe  (ver 19.0.23918.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR /EHa  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /arch:SSE2 /Oi /fp:fast  /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4589 /MP4  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG  /Zi
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR /EHa  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /arch:SSE2 /Oi /fp:fast  /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4589 /MP4  /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /arch:SSE2 /Oi /fp:fast    /MP4  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG  /Zi
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /arch:SSE2 /Oi /fp:fast    /MP4  /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:X86  /INCREMENTAL:NO  /debug
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:X86  /debug /INCREMENTAL
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32 vfw32
    3rdparty dependencies:       zlib libjpeg libwebp libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 core flann imgproc ml photo video imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect superres ts features2d calib3d stitching videostab
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python2 python3 viz

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI:
    QT:                          NO
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    OpenGL support:              NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O:
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.8)
    JPEG:                        build (ver 90)
    WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.19)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
    GDAL:                        NO

  Video I/O:
    Video for Windows:           YES
    DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    DC1394 2.x:                  NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      codec:                     YES (ver 56.41.100)
      format:                    YES (ver 56.36.101)
      util:                      YES (ver 54.27.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)
      resample:                  NO
      gentoo-style:              YES
    GStreamer:                   NO
    OpenNI:                      NO
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    OpenNI2:                     NO
    PvAPI:                       NO
    GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            NO
    XIMEA:                       NO
    Intel PerC:                  NO

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Other third-party libraries:
    Use IPP:                     9.0.1 [9.0.1]
         at:                     E:/Dev/opencv/sources/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_win
    Use IPP Async:               NO
    Use Eigen:                   NO
    Use Cuda:                    NO
    Use OpenCL:                  YES
    Use custom HAL:              NO

  OpenCL:
    Version:                     dynamic
    Include path:                E:/Dev/opencv/sources/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Use AMDFFT:                  NO
    Use AMDBLAS:                 NO

  Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 NO

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 C:/Python34/python.exe (ver 3.4.3)

  Python (for build):            C:/Python34/python.exe

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Matlab:
    mex:                         C:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/mex.bat
    Compiler/generator:          Not working (bindings will not be generated)

  Documentation:
    Doxygen:                     NO
    PlantUML:                    NO

  Tests and samples:
    Tests:                       YES
    Performance tests:           YES
    C/C++ Examples:              NO

  Install path:                  E:/Dev/opencv/x86_v140_xp/install

  cvconfig.h is in:              E:/Dev/opencv/x86_v140_xp
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Just for documentation, works fine using g++ and clang++.

Comment: are you using debug libraries in release build or vice-versa?

Comment: Bullseye! I was using debugging the application in Debug mode using Release OpenCV library. Thanks @Micka!

Comment: mat.at<Vec4b>(i, j);  >> Try swapping i,j here, I suspect you are swapping rows/columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just to add on to [Micka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2393191/micka)'s comment (thanks!), and for my future self...

The reason why my application fails is due to the mixing of **Release** libraries in the **Debug** environment. I was Visual Studio 2015's Property sheet which does not let me add different libraries for different build settings.

However, I later learned that it's possible however to edit the Property sheet using a text editor. By adding the `Condition` attribute I can separate the include and library paths and files.

Here is a sample of what it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludePath>$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);$(WindowsSdk_71A_IncludePath)</IncludePath>
    <LibraryPath>$(LibraryPath)</LibraryPath>
    <_PropertySheetDisplayName>OCV</_PropertySheetDisplayName>
    <ExcludePath>$(VC_IncludePath);$(MSBuild_ExecutablePath);$(VC_LibraryPath_x86);</ExcludePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
        <!-- debug config -->
        <ClCompile>
          <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>E:\Dev\opencv\build\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
          <PreprocessorDefinitions>__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS;UNICODE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
        </ClCompile>
        <Link>
          <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>E:\Dev\opencv\x86_v140_xp\lib\Debug;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
          <AdditionalDependencies>opencv_calib3d310d.lib;opencv_core310d.lib;opencv_features2d310d.lib;opencv_flann310d.lib;opencv_highgui310d.lib;opencv_imgcodecs310d.lib;opencv_imgproc310d.lib;opencv_ml310d.lib;opencv_objdetect310d.lib;opencv_photo310d.lib;opencv_shape310d.lib;opencv_stitching310d.lib;opencv_superres310d.lib;opencv_ts310d.lib;opencv_video310d.lib;opencv_videoio310d.lib;opencv_videostab310d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
        </Link>
    </ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
        <!-- release config -->
        <ClCompile>
          <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>E:\Dev\opencv\build\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
          <PreprocessorDefinitions>__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS;UNICODE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
        </ClCompile>
        <Link>
          <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>E:\Dev\opencv\x86_v140_xp\lib\Release;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
          <AdditionalDependencies>opencv_calib3d310.lib;opencv_core310.lib;opencv_features2d310.lib;opencv_flann310.lib;opencv_highgui310.lib;opencv_imgcodecs310.lib;opencv_imgproc310.lib;opencv_ml310.lib;opencv_objdetect310.lib;opencv_photo310.lib;opencv_shape310.lib;opencv_stitching310.lib;opencv_superres310.lib;opencv_ts310.lib;opencv_video310.lib;opencv_videoio310.lib;opencv_videostab310.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
        </Link>
    </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

You can also replace `Win32` with `x64` for x64 builds.